# The safest way for storing Rest url

Tags: android, security, android-ndk, android-security

I did a lot of research but I did not find a solution. I developed an android application which is communicating with our restful web server. The URL for the request are stored into C files and read using the Android NDK. I know that this method is not safe, so what should I do instead/in addition to keep my urls safe?

Comment: its up to you if you want people to see able to read/write to that URL. usually when you use an API, you need to have an API Key. Without it, the URL will display an error message.... that is probably your best bet.

Comment: @DroiDev But where do I hide the API key then? An attacker can reverse engineer the app and therefore the api key.

Comment: try to use token in your api while receiving request and sending, if attacker will get url then he can't do anything without token.

Comment: i cant tell you how to do it with C. ive done it with javascript...hopefully you get a better answer..... but you basically have to create a way to make a token, and add the authentication for add/update/delete/edit (whatever you need it for)

Comment: Why do you want to make your api url a secret? It's not necessary, it would be security by obscurity (a bad practice), and it's impossible anyway.